# Cant push to git, Failed to connect url:443 no error

Tags: git, github, ssh, push

Ok Ive tried everything on the other questions to try and fix this. Ive tired to change proxy and opened port. I turned off my firewall for that as well, but with no luck D: I get the next message:

"fatal: unable to access 'url' Failed connect to github.com:443; No errror"

Ive tried over SSH as well and I get a Bad File Number error but with port 22.

If I try ssh -T git@ssh.github.com to test it out I get:

"ssh: connect to host url port 22: Bad file number"

Weird thing is Ive yet to encounter an error I can debug. Any ideas? :P

Comment: if you try simply a telnet, does it work?: telnet github.com 443

Comment: the screen goes black and cant do anything. Im not sure what message Im suppose to see. I think the connection is not being succesful with telnet either. EDIT: If I try to conncet only through telnet github.com the connection fails. And if I try telnet github.com 443 the screen goes black for a few min and then back to normal cmd

Comment: The screen went black because the connection was successful. So you are able to connect directly (not via a proxy) to github on 443. Did you try downloading a new git client?

Comment: nop not yet I got the version 1.9.5.msysgit.0

Comment: I went ahead and uninstall the git and installed the new version. Version 2.7.2 but still get the same error D:

Comment: Now when I try to do the git push I get a Bad access

Answer (score 0):

Well I found the problem. In my case a program was blocking ports 22 and 443. I had not notice it was stuck there. I had closed down the program but apparently it froze or something. I restarted my PC and it was gone. Now I was able to push lol.